# Segmentation fault 11 Objective-C, but not in C

Tags: objective-c, c, image, cocoa, bitmap

I'm currently trying to create a 16 bit/channel or 48bpp image as an array in Objective-C, then put it in a `NSBitmapImageRep`. For a start, I want to just fill it with noise to see if it works, so I'm using a C for loop, and for some reason it creates a Segmentation Fault 11, and I can't see how that's possible. I've tried this EXACT code snippet in a simple `.c` file, and it works absolutely fine. By the way this is happening in the main function of the app, I want it to be done from a method on the click of a button, but don't know how I'd access the array from there as it is not global(could do with a couple of tips about that too). 
Also i've tried using `uint8_t` instead of 16 bit pixels, doesn't make a difference.

```
int sizeElements = 1880 * 1056 * 3;
int sizeBytes = sizeElements * sizeof(uint16_t);
uint16_t * imagearray = (uint16_t *)malloc(sizeBytes);
for (int i = 1; i < sizeElements; i++) 
{
    imagearray[i] = rand() % 65536;
}
NSBitmapImageRep * theBitmap = [
    [NSBitmapImageRep alloc] 
    initWithBitmapDataPlanes: (unsigned char * _Nullable * _Nullable)imagearray
    pixelsWide: 1880
    pixelsHigh: 1056
    bitsPerSample: 16
    samplesPerPixel: 3
    hasAlpha: NO 
    isPlanar: NO 
    colorSpaceName: @"NSDeviceRGBColorSpace"
    bitmapFormat: 0 
    bytesPerRow: 1880 * 3 * 2
    bitsPerPixel: 48
];
```

Thanks to anyone who knows, this has been hurting me for hours :(

edit: initialising with NULL as bitmap data planes gets rid of the fault, but so does removing the for loop. Why is this and how can i get it working?

EDIT: adding & like this: `&imagearray` helped, thanks @everyoneWhoAnswered

Comment: Any reason you're not initializing the first element of the array? Also, are you checking that the call to `malloc` succeeded? Note that just because it doesn't crash in C doesn't necessarily mean that the same bug doesn't exist there. It just means it didn't trigger a crash there.

Comment: Why wouldn't you set the element [0]?

Comment: @user1118321 Thanks for pointing out that random thing, but it didn't help, I probably did that while trying to find the bug.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I think I probably did that trying to find the problem, but it turned out it wan't that causing the problem. Thank you anyway for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

The array of planes is not the pixel data, it's an array of pointers to pixel data. You need to put another array in between.

In your case, since your image is not planar, that's an array with the pixel data pointer in its first element, and the others set to NULL.

Comment: Or, just pass `&imageArray` instead of `imageArray`.

Comment: @user1118321 and uliwitness Thanks, completey forgot about trying that. Thanks a lot! sorry about the noobyness.